# about the table of AbpUserLoginAttempts

Tags: asp.net, abp, boilerplate

I had update all the packages of Abp and Net .
and I am runing the project .

but I got the message like
Invalid column name 'FailReason'.    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ......

i had got then sql
**SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO [AbpUserLoginAttempts] ([BrowserInfo], [ClientIpAddress], [ClientName], [CreationTime], [FailReason], [Result], [TenancyName], [TenantId], [UserId], [UserNameOrEmailAddress]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id] VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9);**

in the sql there a column named FailReason.but in the table of AbpUserLoginAttempts of the database ,there is not the column named FailReason.

why ? is there an update that add the column ?

thank you for your help